# How to fill up a list using a for loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

My goal is to create a list of numerical values starting at a lower bound a to an upper bound b with n equal increments. I have to that for very large values. I thought that using a for loop would easily do the work, but it is not working and I can't see where my mistake is.

I use the following code and it returns NA

```
a <- 20
b <- 2
n <- 18
inc < (a-b)/n

l <-c(b)

for ( i in n) {
l[i+1] <- l[i] + inc
}
```

I expected the following result

```
[2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 , 16 , 17 , 18 ,19 , 20]
```

Instead, I get the following :
 `[2 , NA , NA , ... ]`

Comment: You should not use loops for this in R. You can simply use `l <- seq(b,a)` if the increment is 1.

Comment: By the way, this is not a list, but a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. I had to initiate the list with the right space by adding this piece of code before. `l <- numeric(n)` and then I adde the first element to initialize it. `l[1] <- b`

Sorry, rookie mistake !

Comment: Also use ‘for( i in 1:n )’

Comment: Yes, please see, ```1:5``` or ```seq(from = 1, to = 5, by = 1)``` or ```?seq```.  While R allows for loops and sometimes they are necessary,  R also has vectorization which hides the loops. For example ```a = 1:5; b = 6:10; a + b``` note I'm using semi-colon because I cannot do line breaks in comments.

Comment: You increment a vector by adding a new element to the vector. e.g. `v <- c(1, 2)`  to add `3` to `v` then `v <- c(v, 3)` yields `1 2 3`  As noted by RHertel, best to use the seq function for this task.  ?seq will explain it to you.